# mcisendstring repeat function not working

Tags: windows, mci

Running the code below, the video doesn't repeat, just stops at the end. It used to work:

```
    dim moviewindow as picturebox
    dim filename as string= Chr(34) & "C:\test.mp4" & Chr(34)

    mciSendString("open " & filename & " type mpegvideo alias myMovie parent " & moviewindow.Handle.ToInt32 & " style child", vbNullString, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    mciSendString("put myMovie window at 0 0 " & moviewindow.Width & " " & moviewindow.Height, vbNullString, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    mciSendString("setaudio myMovie volume to 0", vbNullString, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    mciSendString("play myMovie notify repeat", vbNullString, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
```

On Windows 10, AMD cards. All graphics drivers up to date. LAV codecs installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you use pinvoke then you *must* check for errors.  If you don't then you cannot find out why "it did not work".  Do not ignore the return value of mciSendString.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I didn't - they were all zeros, but I should have posted these. Transpires it was some issue with my audio drivers. Sorted these and repeat fixed.